# Change color of heatmap labels in Python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to change the color of the `ticklabels` in my heatmap based on some condition. For example below, I would like to change the colors of `ticklabels` containing `A` as `red` and `B` as `green`.

I tried making a list `['red', 'green', 'red', 'green']` and pass it along the color option but no success so far. Any help would be great.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = ['ABC', 'BDF', 'ADF', 'BCF']

data = np.random.random((4,4))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(data, interpolation='nearest')
fig.colorbar(cax)

ax.set_xticklabels(['']+alpha)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+alpha)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the text colour using `set_color` on the label text objects:

```
for l in ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()+ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels():
    if 'A' in l.get_text():
        l.set_color('r')
    elif 'B' in l.get_text():
        l.set_color('g')
```

[image]

Of course, this doesn't address what happens if both `A` and `B` are present in the label (i.e. should `ABC` be red or green)?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much ... the conditions do not overlap so not a problem at all.